# How to make UITextfiled to start text from top

Tags: iphone, xcode

i have uitextfield i wan that it should start entering text from top instead of center my textfield height is 100 how to make this.

```
    IBOutlet UITextField*commentTextField;

    comments=commentTextField.text;
```

Comment: I guess you need a UITextView

Comment: I guess you want to implement multiline TextField, the n you must use UITextView for that, rather then making UITextField's height 100 !!!

Comment: how i will entry data in uitext view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
textfield.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` method of `UITextViewDelegate` and in that check if the replacement text is `\n`, then hide the keyboard.